# C# Reverse all numbers in string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a string:

"*Hello **7866592** this is my **12432** string and **823** i need to flip all **123***"

And i want to to be

"*Hello **2956687** this is my **23421** string and **328** i need to flip all **321***"

I use this regular expression to get all numbers:

```
Regex nums = new Regex("\d+");
```

Comment: One should look into [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) and [reversing strings](http://www.dotnetperls.com/reverse-string)

Comment: There are no normal regular expression language elements that will do this for you. You don't say whether you need the solution to be a regular expression (and that would be a very long and difficult regex, if you can even do it).

That means you seem to be looking for a normal programming solution for a basic problem. I don't think this is appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: Sounds like homework.  Using regular expressions would be good to extract the numbers, but I reckon it'd be best to just increment through the string as an array of chars, record an index point where a set of digits start, then increment until you reach a non-digit, then look at reversing the digits in between index points *a* and *b-1*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
var replacedString = 
    Regex.Replace(//finds all matches and replaces them
    myString, //string we're working with
    @"\d+", //the regular expression to match to do a replace
    m => new string(m.Value.Reverse().ToArray())); //a Lambda expression which
        //is cast to the MatchEvaluator delegate, so once the match is found, it  
        //is replaced with the output of this method.
```

Comment: The important bit here is the replacer function. (Just be glad this isn't Java!)

Comment: Error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string'

Comment: @Danpe sorry fixed, meant to do the `Regex.Replace`, but was typing in a browser.

Comment: Man, you are just awesome!
I whould like if you can add explenation of how it works exactly :)

Comment: +1.  Couldn't haven written it better myself.  This overload of `Regex.Replace` utilizes the `MatchEvaluator`, which allows you to perform any operation you'd like on each individual match.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string on spaces. Then take the strings in the new string array that are digits and run this function on them:

```
public static string Reverse( string s )
{
   char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
   Array.Reverse( charArray );
   return new string( charArray );
}
```

Then recombine your array into a single string.