# Reverse any group of numbers in a string

Tags: c#, string, reverse

I need reverse all group of digit in text for example

```
"test text 145 for 23 site 1"
```

we need this output

```
"test text 541 fro 32 site 1"
```

Comment: That's nice. Where's your attempt?

Comment: I would recommend using [Regex.Replace with a MatcherEvaluator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht1sxswy(v=vs.110).aspx). Should take about 2 lines.

Comment: I Read many example in this site but we need best way

Comment: There is not necessarily a "best" way here - and at this point all you need is a *working* way. Anyway, my vote is above.

Comment: @jozi: do you have *any* way? It's difficult to choose between nothing and nothing

Comment: this is my answare everebody tanks for vote .....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144754/c-sharp-reverse-all-numbers-in-string

Comment: var replacedString = 
    Regex.Replace(//finds all matches and replaces them
    myString, //string we're working with
    @"\d+", //the regular expression to match to do a replace
    m => new string(m.Value.Reverse().ToArray())); //a Lambda expression which
        //is cast to the MatchEvaluator delegate, so once the match is found, it  
        //is replaced with the output of this method.

Comment: your output must be change to ""test text 541 for 32 site 1"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[C# Reverse all numbers in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144754/c-sharp-reverse-all-numbers-in-string)

Thanks to [Yuriy Faktorovich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133910/yuriy-faktorovich)

```
var replacedString = 
Regex.Replace(//finds all matches and replaces them
myString, //string we're working with
@"\d+", //the regular expression to match to do a replace
m => new string(m.Value.Reverse().ToArray())); //a Lambda expression which
    //is cast to the MatchEvaluator delegate, so once the match is found, it  
    //is replaced with the output of this method.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will do something like this... Though not tested

```
public string reverseString(string valuetoReverse)
{
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> newString = valuetoReverse.Split(' ').Reverse().ToList();
    newString.ForEach(v => s.Append(v + String.Empty));
    return s.ToString();
}
```